# Swift 4. Using PATs. Are protocols which reference each other allowed? I'm getting an error I don't understand

Tags: swift, protocols, associated-types

In the code below I set up protocols for vertices and edges in a simple Graph project. The vertices reference edges, and the edges reference vertices. In the `neighbours()` function, I call `map()` on the `edges` array and I get this error:

> 'map' produces '[T]', not the expected contextual result type '[Self.VertexType]'.

```
import Foundation

protocol EdgeProtocol {
    associatedtype VertexType: VertexProtocol
    var from : VertexType { get set }
    var to : VertexType { get set }
    init(from: VertexType, to:VertexType)
}

protocol VertexProtocol  {
    associatedtype EdgeType: EdgeProtocol
    associatedtype VertexType: VertexProtocol
    var id: String { get set }
    var edges: [EdgeType] { get set }
    func neighbours() -> [VertexType]
}

extension VertexProtocol {
    func neighbours() -> [VertexType] {
        return edges.map { $0.to }  // 'map' produces '[T]', not the expected
                                    //  contextual result type '[Self.VertexType]'
    }
}

struct Edge: EdgeProtocol {
    typealias VertexType = Vertex   // leave out -> no compile error
    var from: Vertex
    var to: Vertex
    init(from: Vertex, to:Vertex) {
        self.from = from
        self.to = to
    }
}

class Vertex: VertexProtocol {
    typealias VertexType = Vertex   // leave out -> compile error
    typealias EdgeType = Edge       // leave out -> no compile error

    var id: String
    var edges = [Edge]()
    init(name: String) { id = name }
}
```

My code "knows" that `edges` is of type `[Vertex:VertexProtocol]` but nevertheless `map()` interprets it as [T]. Is this because Swift 4 doesn't allow cross references between protocols or something else?  I must confess I don't really understand PATs (protocols with associated types) as my comment lines indicate. Any guidance appreciated

Comment: Thank you Charles for your very clear explanation and solution. It worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that although `edges` conforms to `EdgeProtocol`, and `EdgeProtocol` contains a `VertexType` associated type, the compiler has no way of knowing that this will be the same type as `VertexProtocol`'s `VertexType` associated type. Both protocols' `VertexType`s are going to conform to `VertexProtocol`, but they may not necessarily  be the same type. Therefore `edges.map { $0.to }` returns `[EdgeType.VertexType]`, but your function is declared to return `[Self.VertexType]`, so it's a type mismatch.

You can fix this by explicitly specifying that both `VertexType`s are the same. You can do that either in the definition:

```
protocol VertexProtocol  {
    associatedtype VertexType
    associatedtype EdgeType: EdgeProtocol where EdgeType.VertexType == VertexType
    // ...
}
```

Or, if that's not practical, you can constrain the extension:

```
extension VertexProtocol where EdgeType.VertexType == VertexType {
    func neighbours() -> [VertexType] {
        return edges.map { $0.to }
    }
}
```

Either of these approaches should result in code that compiles.